# Not able to acess php file in xampp ubuntu through Local host

Tags: php

Hello I have installed xampp/lampp on windows and am trying to open website in local host using:

> http://localhost/htdocs/my-first-project/index.php

I have also tried

> http://localhost/my-first-project/index.php

But it always shows following error:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

But my local host page and phpmyAdmin is running without any problem

I also want to mention that I have set my Apache server port to 8080.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes I have have and I also tried creating a virtual host but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried to place your index.php in the DocumentRoot Folder and access it from there?